# Riak search returns null

Tags: php, nosql, riak, riak-search

I'm trying to work with Riak on PHP. I read the documentation but no luck. So I've already configured the "search" option in /etc/init.d/app.conf as true. So, print_r($results) returns as null array.

```
# Connect to Riak
$client = new RiakClient('127.0.0.1', 8098);

$bucket = $client->bucket("searchbucket");
$bucket->newObject("one", array("foo"=>"one", "bar"=>"red"))->store();
$bucket->newObject("two", array("foo"=>"two", "bar"=>"green"))->store();

# Execute a search for all objects with matching properties
$results = $client->search("searchbucket", "foo:one OR foo:two")->run();


print_r($results);
```

What is wrong with my code? What I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to enabling search in the app.config file, you also need to explicitly enable it for the buckets you want to be able to search. This can be done by [adding a Riak Search commit hook to the bucket properties.](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/cookbooks/Riak-Search---Indexing-and-Querying-Riak-KV-Data/)

If you retrieve the [bucket properties](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/references/apis/http/HTTP-Get-Bucket-Properties/) for 'searchbucket' you should be able to see a commit hook listed.